# How to create a generic list of generics?

Tags: .net, vb.net, generics

Please see my below code, I am trying to create a list of an interface which uses generics, but I need the generic version. So that you're aware, the generic type may differ for each entry in the list, it won't just be a list of IFoo with the same generic type.

Please let me know if you need clarification.

```
Public Interface IFoo

End Interface

Public Interface IFoo(Of T)
    Inherits IFoo

    Function Bar(foo As T) As T

End Interface

Public Class Foo(Of T)
    Implements IFoo(Of T)

    Private ReadOnly Foos As List(Of IFoo)

    Public Function Bar(foo As T) As T Implements IFoo(Of T).Bar
        For Each i In Foos
            ' Can't call Bar function from IFoo(Of T) as IFoo does not define the Bar function. 
        Next
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to call the Bar function from within the Bar function?!

Comment: @Grim May not be the best example but yes, it is similar to my actual scenario. My question is more about how to create a list of IFoo where the generic is unknown and can vary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About generic types, there is something you need to understand is that an object of type `IFoo(Of String)` is a **completely different** type from `IFoo(Of Integer)`, they have almost nothing in common actually.

If `IFoo(Of T)` inherits from `IFoo`, then the only thing they have in common is `IFoo`.

So if you try running a loop and call a method they all have in common, you **must** put that method inside `IFoo`.

Also, even if you could do it, how would you manage the parameter ?

```
 For Each i In Foos
      'Let's say you can call it from here
      Dim Myparam As ??? 'What type is your param then ?
      i.Bar(of <What do you put here ?>)(Myparam)
 Next
```